# Why did my Browser Element doesent show my html string?

Tags: wpf, xaml, webbrowser-control

So I try to work the first time with an Web Browser Element in Wpfl. I tryd to show my html string in the Web Browser Element. I tried it like that:

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty HtmlProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Html",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(Class1),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnHtmlChanged));

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(WebBrowser))]
    public static string GetHtml(WebBrowser d)
    {
        return (string)d.GetValue(HtmlProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHtml(WebBrowser d, string value)
    {
        d.SetValue(HtmlProperty, value);
    }

    static void OnHtmlChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser wb = d as WebBrowser;
        if (wb != null)
            wb.NavigateToString(e.NewValue as string);
    }
```

and in my View my Property like that:

```
private string _html;
    public string html1
    {
        get
        {
            string html = "html string here";
            return _html + html;
        }
        set
        {
            _html = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(html1));
        }
    }
```

and my XAML like that:

```
        <WebBrowser local:Class1.Html="{Binding html}"></WebBrowser>
```

But it dosent show my html string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you set the attached property to a local value? Then you know that your binding to `html` fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works when you set the attached property to a local value like this you know that your binding to `html` fails:

```
<WebBrowser local:Class1.Html="test..."></WebBrowser>
```

Also, you bind to a property called "html" but the one you have posted is named `html1`.

Ensure that you have set the `DataContext` of the control to a class that has a public `html` property that returns a `string`. Then your code should work.

Comment: When I just type "test" like you it dosent show anything either

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in your `OnHtmlChanged` method, does it get hit?

Comment: yes it does  get hit

Comment: So `NavigateToString` is called with the expected value?

Comment: He jump in the " wb.NavigateToString(e.NewValue as string);" but it dosent show anything

Comment: Are you actually seeing the `WebBrowser` at all then, with out without your property?

Comment: yes the e.new value got the value test

Comment: Now I can see the Value Test, the Browser Element dosent show up but when I try to use my html string then it doesent work

Comment: You can see the local value but not the bounded one? Then it is something wrong with the binding and/or the value. Try to return "test123" from the source property.

Comment: Now I see the Problem, my html stuff dosent work on that, when I put different html in then it work, but thank you for your time